# Job shop scheduling using simulated annealing metaheuristic

Tags: graph, scheduling, simulated-annealing

I am implementing a job shop scheduler using Simulated Annealing - each instance is represented by a disjunctive graph [(described here)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_graph).
Basically, the neighbourhood action for the metaheuristic is inverting a randomly chosen disjunctive arc that lies on the critical path. The problem is that with some instances the metaheuristic reaches a point where the critical path in the graph only consists of conjunctive arcs, which leads to a situation when no arc can be inverted.
Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: I've got an job shop scheduling implementation with simulated annealing (but by default it now uses late acceptance because that has better results). The model is very different though. Maybe you find some inspiration in the [implementation](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling).

Answer (score 0):

If you have only conjunctive arcs on the critical path, you are dealing with technological precedence constraints (i.e. operations in the same job). There's nothing you can do to shorten those. I think you may have found the best solution in this case.